# jQuery - count elements until you reach a specific element and stop count

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I would like to achieve is that the following code counts the `siblings` but stops at the `sibling` that does not meet the requirement.

So for instance the bellow example instead of getting 6 in its count it would return 4 as it would count from active to the first `fieldset` not to have the `percent class`.

Something like : `$("fieldset.active").andSelf().siblings('fieldset.percent').stop().not('.percent').length;`

Bellow is a working start point of the code.

```js
var jump = $("fieldset.active").andSelf().siblings('fieldset.percent').length;

$('.result').html('Counted: '+jump);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
0 - dont Count
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="active">
1 - count me
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
2 - count me
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
3 - count me
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
4 - count me
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
5 Stop here - dont Count
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
6 - dont Count
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
7 - dont Count
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
8 - dont Count
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
9 - dont Count
</fieldset>
<div class="result"></div>
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your current code, you can use this :

```
$("fieldset.active")
  .first() // Select the first active class
  .nextUntil(':not(fieldset.percent)') // Select all field after untill you hit a field that doesn't have .percent class
  .addBack() // Add the first element
  .length; // Get the length
```

Of course, depending on your exact code, there is additional variables. This works with the given snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `andSelf()` was deprecated since jQuery 1.8 (and you're using jQuery 1.9). Use `addBack()` instead.

With that considered, you can do:

```js
var jump = $("fieldset.active:eq(0)").nextUntil(':not(.percent)').addBack().length;

$('.result').html('Counted: '+jump);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
0 - dont Count
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="active">
1 - count me
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
2 - count me
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
3 - count me
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
4 - count me
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
5 Stop here - dont Count
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
6 - dont Count
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
7 - dont Count
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
8 - dont Count
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="percent">
9 - dont Count
</fieldset>
<div class="result"></div>
```